# How to import shared data sources located on my report server to Visual Studio reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have around 20 data shared sources created directly by me on the web report server.
Now i started to use Visual Studio instead of report builder.

How can I import all these shared data sources to my newly created VS solution?
I don't want to create them again.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no built-in functionality to do this. You could probably script something to do most of the work, but you would have to generate unique ID's and build the XML structure, write it to a file etc. For 20, it's not worth it, you could do them by hand in under an hour.